# Assuming the structure of the json string does not change, is the order of a jsonpath match value result stable?

Tags: python, json, jsonpath, dictionary-comprehension

Assuming the structure of the json string does not change, is the order of a jsonpath match value result stable?

```
import jsonpath_ng

response = json.loads(response)

jsonpath_expression_name = jsonpath_ng.parse("$[forms][0][questionGroups][*][questions]..[name]")
match_name = [match.value for match in jsonpath_expression_name.find(response)]

jsonpath_expression_id = jsonpath_ng.parse("$[forms][0][questionGroups][*][questions]..[id]")
matches_id = [match.value for match in jsonpath_expression_id.find(response)]

survey_q_dict = { k:v for (k,v) in zip(matches_id, match_name)}
```

Thank you!

Comment: The parser [seems stable](https://replit.com/@oluwafemisule/TestStabilityJSONParseNG#main.py)